# Install a Jekyll site inside a Wordpress subdomain

Tags: wordpress, jekyll, subdomain

I have a Wordpress site and I'd like to create a subdomain for it (blog.site.com) and have my existing Jekyll blog be in this subdomain (it is currently hosted separately in Github Pages).

I know I could redirect the subdomain to the existing Jekyll blog, but I'd prefer to have it inside the Wordpress structure while still being able to build it locally and deploy it to Github.

Comment: Who is Jekyll? What server are you using for WP? Are you confident in managing domains and hosting?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you will need to add a `CNAME` file to your GitHub repository with `blog.example.com` (see [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-a-subdomain)). This will allow you to have your Jekyll site hosted at blog.example.com without affecting anything at example.com or [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).